vscode notebook cannot load js from url
from IPython.display import HTML
HTML('''\n            <!DOCTYPE html>\n            <html lang="en" style="height: 100%">\n   
         <head>\n            <meta charset="utf-8">\n            </head>\n       
     <body style="height: 100%; margin: 0">\n\n            \n       
     <div id="test" style="height: 600px; width: 800px"></div>\n            \n   

  <script type="text/javascript" src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/echarts/5.5.0/echarts.min.js'></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
        console.log(echarts);
         var dom = document.getElementById(\'test\');\n   
         dom.innerHTML = ""\n            
              var myChart = echarts.init(dom, null, {\n            
    renderer: \'canvas\',\n                useDirtyRect: false\n                });\n            var app = {};\n\n      
      var option;\n    option = {"grid": {},
"yAxis": {}, 
"xAxis": {}, 
"series": [{"type": "bar", data:[[1,2],[2,3]]}] , 
"port": "5001"};   
    if (option && typeof option === \'object\') {\n         
       myChart.setOption(option);\n                }\n\n      
        </script>\n        </body>\n        </html>\n    ''')

I run this code in jupyter lab, it works well.
But failed in vscode notebook.

Can anyone help me fix it?

Where is echarts supposed to come from?

I have serve it in my local url. You can also use public url 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/echarts/5.5.0/echarts.min.js'
